# Cmposer LUIS error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ( in corporate network)

Tags: bots, azure-language-understanding

I am using Bot FrameWork Composer to create a bot. I am facing an issue when i am connecting composer to LUIS application using Primary Key. 
NOTE:- I am only using Composer , Emulator and LUIS 
Environment :- windows machine using Corporate network

Error:- getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Could you help please.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by your url site be reached over internet, Azure app service was unable to reach the URL

Resolution

=========

You can use the Vnet integration feature to integrate your on premise server with Azure as in the document below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#accessing-on-premises-resources

Alternatively If your site can be accessed over a internet, the app service should be able to connect to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Let me check this , I will get back to you.